# Do I need hide .htacces 302 redirection from search engines

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, search-engine, robots.txt

I added .htaccess redirection like this

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 302 /youtube https://www.youtube.com
Redirect 302 /youtube-not-public https://www.youtube.com/not-public
```

I would like to hide `/youtube-not-public` from indexing and make it not able to display in web search engines.

Do I need to create `robots.txt` or use other solution? Eg.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /youtube-not-public
```

Comment: Yes, robots.txt approach works

Comment: (Aside: `RewriteEngine` also has nothing to do with `Redirect` - they are different modules.)